# Profanity filter doesn't work (php)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, error-handling

Code :

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql17.000webhost.com","login","pwd","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
  }

$filter = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bad_words");

$content = mysqli_fetch_array( $filter );

$old_word = $_POST("input");
$old_word = str_ireplace($content['word'], '[foul]', $old_word);

$filtered_word = $old_word;
Print($filtered_word);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Error message :

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/a7593238/public_html/bad_filter.php on line 13

Please help.

Comment: $_POST("input") is incorrect, the correct way is $_POST["input"]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling the superglobal array `$_POST` like a function. It is an array variable and you need to access them using the square brackets.

Like this.

```
$old_word = $_POST["input"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$old_word = $_POST("input");
```

with

```
$old_word = $_POST["input"];
```